# При загрузке данных с сервера выдает ошибку javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть кнопка:

```
<button id="LoadBtn" class="btn btn-default">Load</button>
```

И скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function () {            
    $('body').on('click', '#LoadBtn', function () {                
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:55285/api/values/',
            type: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {                        
                WriteResponse(data);
            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
                alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Если убрать обработчик и сделать вот так, то все работает:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:55285/api/values/',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {                        
            WriteResponse(data);
        },
        error: function (x, y, z) {
            alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
        }
    });                    
});
```

Нужно что бы загрузились данные с сервера и оправились в `WriteResponse`. А вылетает `[object Object] error`.
Подскажите в чем ошибка, не могу разобраться.

Comment: а что вы пытаетесь сделать, вы не написали

Comment: подправил данные.

Comment: да, хочется по нажатию кнопки выводить данные. Чем верхний пример с $('body').on('click', '#LoadBtn', function () { ... }); неверен?

Comment: а что присылает сервер?

Comment: public IQueryable<Contact> Get()
        {                      
            return repository.Contacts;
        } возвращает сервер, и данные там точно есть

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41106/discussion-between-stranger-in-the-q-and-2felix).

Answer (score 1):

Вся проблема была в `bootstrap` классе `navbar-form navbar-left`.
В этом классе лежала кнопка. Как только переместил ее в другой `div` с другим классом, все заработало. Почему - не имею понятия.